# Trouble using requests library in python

Tags: python, security

I am attempting to check for active web site folders against a list that was created using robots.txt (this is for learning security, Im doing this on a server that I own and control). I am using Python 2.7 on Kali Linux.

My code works if I just do one web address at a time, as I get a proper 200 or 404 response for folders that are active and not working, respectively.

When I attempt to this against the entire list, I get a string of 404 errors. When i print out actual addresses that the script is creating, everything looks correct.

Here is the code that I am doing:

```
import requests
attempt = open('info.txt', 'r')
folders = attempt.readlines()

for line in folders:
    host = 'http://10.0.1.66/mutillidae'+line
    attempt = requests.get(host)
    print attempt
```

This results in a string of 404 errors. If I take the loop out, and try each one individually, I get a 200 response back showing that it is up and running.

I have also printed out the address using the same loop against the text document that contains the correct folders, and the addresses seem to look fine which I verified through copy and pasting. I have tried this with a file containing multiple folders and a single folder listed, and always get a 404 when attempting to read from the file.

The info.txt file contains the following:

```
/passwords/
/classes/
/javascript/
/config
/owasp-esapi-php/
/documentation/
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: have a look at the value of `host`. there might still be line endings in there.

Comment: Can you show us the code that works?   Also, before alKid edited your question, the code you said that you are using had a typo in it.   So is it _really_ the code you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lines returned by `file.readlines()` contain trailing newlines, which you must remove before passing them to `requests.get`. Replace the statement:

```
host = 'http://10.0.1.66/mutillidae'+line
```

with:

```
host = 'http://10.0.1.66/mutillidae' + line.rstrip()
```

and the problem will go away.

Note that your code would be easier to read if you refrained from using the same generic variable name such as `attempt` for different purposes, all in the same scope. Also, one should try to use variable names that reflect their usage—for example, `host` would be better named `url`, as it doesn't hold the host name, but the entire URL.